# Performing UpdateLayout on SizeChanged event of ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight, xaml, layout, silverlight-4.0, scrollbar

**UPDATED**
I have an obtuse requirement I'm trying to fulfill working with existing elements and I'm at a point I could really use another pair of eyes.

For quicker explanation, some pseudo;

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Grid/>
   <Grid Grid.Row="1"/>
   <Grid Grid.Row="2"/>

   <Grid Grid.Row="3" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
          <ItemsControl/>
        </ScrollViewer/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

So what we have here is a parent `Grid` with a child `Grid` whose visibility gets toggled. Currently the parent's row has an Auto height set so when the child disappears, the row collapses.

Originally, there was just a `MaxHeight` set on the child which invoked the `ScrollViewer` scrollbar just fine when it's made visible. Except I need to ditch the `MaxHeight` and let it take up all the space it has available/needs and at the same time invoke the scrollbar on the `ScrollViewer` when the size changes. I should also mention I'm trying to accomplish this entire in XAML with no code behind if I can.

I tried rigging an `EventTrigger` to `SizeChanged` and also tried `Loaded` and let it do a `CallMethodAction` to perform `UpdateLayout` hoping it would re-draw/measure the `ScrollViewer` to invoke the scrollbar if it's required. However no joy...

Something like this attached to the `ScrollViewer`;

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
       <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="UpdateLayout"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I'm hoping someone who's got more sleep than I have can offer some insight to my folly or what I'm forgetting? Seems like something like this should work.

All I need it to do, is still respect the `Visibility` change and allow the parent's row to collapse, but still invoke a scrollbar when it's Visible and it's required. Any tricks?

PS - I'm also trying InvalidateArrange & InvalidateMeasure with no luck, am I perhaps using CallMethodAction incorrectly in this scenario?

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the `Height="Auto"` setting from the second row in the outer Grid? That would make that row fill exactly the available space and toggle the scrollbar automatically.

Comment: @Clemens then when the content filling it is collapsed it stays the size of what was there leaving a nice big blank space. Unfortunately tried a number of different ways like that.

Comment: Ok, it should work if you also set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` on the outer Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `VerticalAlignment="Top"` and no `Height` (or `Height="*"`) on the second RowDefinition in the outer Grid should work:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I updated the layout in the question, I thought the couple of rows would convey the example but I'm thinking not. Unfortunately this still leaves a space and doesn't invoke scrollbar, so I'm assuming the * above it in the parent has effect? It's amazing how the seemingly most inane things can become the biggest pain in the *$# lol

Comment: Are you perhaps just confusing the indices? You've got `Height="*"` on the 3rd row, but the collapsed inner Grid has `Grid.Row="3"`, which is the 4th row.

Comment: Nah the way it's setup was an adhoc way of fulfilling requirements at the time but it wasn't really made to do what it does. So you have visibility getting toggled on content of all the rows but the * one which pushes the others around as they expand/collapse so the center can be made to take more or less space as the content around it is toggled in and out. (I know, I know... )